# Odd unexpected indent error in Python

Tags: python

I know there's many questions with the same title, but non like my problem.

I'm trying to use a class from a another script on a new script, but I get an indent error on the same line I'm importing the script. It's odd cause there's no indentation or spaces and I've checked. Backspaced many time and nothing. Here's the `.py` where I'm importing the class:

```
from logInScreen import checkValidation #the undexpected indent is on this line


class hello:

    cv = checkValidation()

    def show(self):

        print(self.cv.user)

h = hello()

h.show()
```

THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE! I named the `hello` class differently.

This is a bit of the class I'm trying to import from another `.py`. I'll show just before the 1st method cause That's all I'm using.

```
class checkValidation:

    fail = 0

    user = "name"

    password = "1234"
```

Here's I picture of the error:

[image]

I know it sounds stupid, but I can't seems to find a way to fix it. I made sure both scripts are on the same folder.

Comment: Can you add the error you are receiving?

Comment: sure thing, I'll edit and add it

Comment: Shouldn't the `print(self.cv.usr)` command be indented as it is a part of `def show(self)` ?

Comment: yes, I missed that. it's indented on my program

Comment: What happens when you do a copy/paste rather than an import?

Comment: Show us `logInScreen.py` line 61 and the surrounding lines.

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: What @gnibbler said. This almost *always* comes up because you're mixing tabs and spaces on accident (which often happens when copying and pasting).

Comment: Looks like the indentation error is coming from the file you are importing.

Comment: I found it!!!!! On the program I'm importing, line 61 has 5 spaces instead 4 lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 61 had 5 spaces instead 4

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has nothing to do with any of the code you've posted. The traceback shows that on line 61 of `logInScreen.py`, the line

```
os.system("mainPage3.py 1")
```

is indented more than it should be. Take a look at that line and the lines surrounding it, and figure out what level it should be indented to.

If the indentation looks fine, see if you're mixing tabs and spaces. If you are, convert the tabs to spaces. Python handles tabs like Notepad does, as enough spaces to reach the next 8-space indentation level. That is almost certainly not what you were expecting.